# Is there a way to hide a div in Blazor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, blazor

I am using Blazor and I want to hide the sidebar when I press on the navbar-toggler-icon. The list items collaps but the problem is that the div is still there.

[image]

```
    <div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="nav-top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="CheckCollapse">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">NavBar</a>
        </div>

        <div class="@NavMenuCssClass">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item px-0">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                        <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-0">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                        <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-0">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = false;

    public string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void CheckCollapse()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually defined a CSS class named `collapse`?

Comment: CSS still has plenty of uses, but the selective display of components or elements is very much what Blazor is all about.  I wouldn't use CSS for that unless you are preloading a lot of images for a slideshow, and you want to keep them all in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier than you think.

```
@if(!collapseNavMenu)
{
    <div class="sidebar">
      ... as before
    </div>
}
```