# How to use Java script or jQuery inside blazor component server side to show and hide input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, blazor-server-side

I working on `blazor` web applications `.NET core 7` server side . I face issue I can't use jQuery to show and hide input text box based on drop down selection .

inside `blazor component on serverNames.Razor` page

I need to show text box input based on select Server name from drop down using JQUERY .

I don't have index.html on my `blazor web application` .

drop down and input text as below :

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-3 col-form-label">SearchBy</label>
        <select id="ddlOptionSearch" class="form-select">
            <option value="0">--Select--</option>
            <option value="1">Server Name</option>
            <option value="2">Server Type</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    <div id="dvSearch" style="display: none">
        Server Number:
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtServerName" />
    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery script that show and hide as below

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ddlOptionSearch").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "Server Name") {
                console.log("server name selected");
                $("#dvSearch").show();
            } else {
                $("#dvSearch").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**How to use jQuery script to display input text box when select Server Name from drop down?**

**Updated answer**

if there are solution by c# can do that I accept it .

updated answer

I get error below after apply posted solution

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')
    at j (blazor.server.js:1:17509)
    at blazor.server.js:1:20768
    at se.updateComponent (blazor.server.js:1:20793)
    at blazor.server.js:1:118191
    at Hn.processBatch (blazor.server.js:1:118563)
    at Ft.<anonymous> (blazor.server.js:1:133366)
    at Ft._invokeClientMethod (blazor.server.js:1:75072)
    at Ft._processIncomingData (blazor.server.js:1:72696)
    at Ft.connection.onreceive (blazor.server.js:1:67009)
    at i.onmessage (blazor.server.js:1:51322)
blazor.server.js:1 [2023-03-13T13:25:21.637Z] Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild'))
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

[image: issue relate to remove child]

Comment: Why jQuery and not C# ?

Comment: ok if you have solution on csharp i accept it so please help me

Comment: It depends on how (or if) you want to bind the select value to a C# var. Hiding can be done with an `@if()` or with `hidden=true`  For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68020569/60761

Comment: can you please tell me by details code please

Comment: Hi , change `if ($(this).val() == "Server Name")..` to `if ($(this).val() == "1")..` because `.val()` will return the `value=".."` not the text which in between the option tag.

Comment: can you help me by code details step by step please if possible

Comment: I updated my answer check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- add javascript in separated file in wwwroot 
2- embed jquery cdn _Host.cshtml file

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

after

```
 <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

3-add js file in _Host.cshtml file

```
<script src="/JS/MyJavaScript.js"></script>
```

4- your js code in js file should be like:

```
$(document).on("change", "#ddlOptionSearch", function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
        console.log("server name selected");
        $("#dvSearch").show();
    } else {
        $("#dvSearch").hide();
    }
})
```

[image]